# что за хостинг i2p.online и почему для него доступны только поддомены?

Tags: безопасность, hosts

Смотрел видео про `gitlab`, и там ведущий заходил на сам сайт через `gitlab.i2p.online`. При этом сам сайт `i2p.online` напрямую недоступен. Что это за хостинг такой (`i2p.online`), кому-нибудь известно?

Comment: потому что: `<?php exit(header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found")); ?>`

Comment: Это не хостинг, а гейт в I2P сеть